# Take json value inside a dataframe

Tags: python, json, tweepy

api.search for keyword mining.Here is my tweepy code

```
for i in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="kurir pos",tweet_mode="extended").items(10):
    author.append(i.author)
    contributors.append(i.contributors)
```

As you can see for user they return us json inside a dataframe.As you can see username is in json.screen_name
Row 1 of dataframe [username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO3qa.png)

I already can get the screen_name by using

```
for i in df.iterrows():
    x = df['user']
    for j in x:
        y = [j.screen_name]
        print(y)
```

it gets a result of

```
['kring_pajak']
['kring_pajak']
['ManoharaSekar']
['kbrindns']
```

in my pycharm console variabel `y` only return a last value of the loop so its different from my `print` result,I try something like

```
y = j.[screen_name]
h = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

But got an error
`ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

I try also append,to_dataframe but it got an error.Can anyone tell me how to change the tweepy so i can get the username or I really appreciated about change variabel `y` into dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you are looking for, but his builds a small dataframe of unique user names.

```
username = set()
for tweet in Cursor(api.search,q="kurir pos",tweet_mode="extended").items(10):
    print(tweet.user.screen_name)
    username.add(tweet.user.screen_name)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(username), columns=['username'])
df

        username
0       mas_pos_
1    kring_pajak
2      Tokokopii
3     yeolmoonie
4  dittaafebrian
```